# SharePoint Designer Replace List Item Permission missing

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a problem, i am trying to remove users access when they submit the infopath form with SharePoint designer, however i am missing all the remove or replace list item permission in my SP designer.
Regards 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add `Impersonation Step`, It will allow to add permission related actions.

[image]

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: can you send me the screenshot i cant find it.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FLkiIZ.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F5234%2Fhow-does-accepting-an-answer-work&docid=7KEkF9vmblR8BM&tbnid=lsrThuSnChOq-M%3A&vet=1&w=300&h=251&bih=662&biw=1366&ved=0ahUKEwikmYTl6c_QAhUDS48KHUUsBegQMwgdKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8